# Jquery Ajax in Django: Can't POST data to url

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, post

I have never tried Ajax before until today but as it stands, here is what I am trying to do. I want to pass the `value="***"` of my button `on.click` to my `views.py` file so it can be stored in a variable and here is what I have so far:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.csrftoken();
        $('#btnRestaurant').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'categories': $(this).val(),
                }
                url: "project_name/views.py",
                success: function(data){
                    params = data;
                    alert(params);
                }
                error:  error: function(){           
                    alert("Error")
                }
                cache:true
            });
            $('#btnActive').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        'categories': $(this).val(),
                    }
                    url: "project_name/views.py",
                    success: function(data){
                        params = data,
                        alert(params),
                    }
                    error: function(){         
                        alert("Error")
                    }
                });
            });
</script>
```

And my buttons:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id=btnRestaurant value="restaurant")>Food</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id=btnActive value="beauty salon">Hair/Clothes</button>
```

As it stands though I don't even receive an alert back saying if it has been successful or not.

Comment: A first step to debug more comfortably is to use the webdeveloper tools in Chrome or Firefox. If you open them up, the console will show you Javascript errors and in case of Ajax which status codes you get back. You could check if you find something there and then update the question with more details.

Comment: Looks like a CSRF protection issue, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#ajax for more info.

Comment: Ok so i copy the function to get my csrf token and what exactly do i do with it?

Comment: ill edit it now its in, still doesn't work though

Comment: @aumo the posted javascript code has a few issues (missing `,`, missing function wrapper around  `error` callback, `url` points to `project_name/views.py` instead of a url endpoint). `CSRF` is not unlikely to become an issue too, but I think it would be better to get information from the OP's console log, because if that is the original JS from the source code then the error chain starts earlier.

Comment: @sthz where abouts can i find it on chrome?

Comment: E.g. you can right click on the page and select `Inspect elements`. Here are the official [docs from Google](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools). When they are open start using it by finding the tab called console. If there are errors with Javascript (or Ajax requests), everything will show up there. It doesn't make debugging fun; but at least it makes it possible. ;)

Comment: Looked through and the only error it is showing is api http error 0 ? Forget that, that is something adblocker has blocked :/ back to square one

Comment: Did you get any further with this? Also, is the Javascript code you posted exactly the same code that you are using in your project?

Comment: Still didn't get any further I have now altered the code again but to no avail as the ajax still wont work